# php array manipulation in multidimensional arrays. getting data in array form with all have the same keys

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a result of arrays that has contain like this:

```
array(
   [0]=>array(
       ["id"]=>56,
       ["name"]=>"john",
       ["company_id"]=>1,
       ["profession"]=>"IT";
   )
   [1]=>array(
       ["id"]=>57,
       ["name"]=>"jane",
       ["company_id"]=>2,
       ["profession"]=>"QC Assistant";
   )
   [2]=>array(
       ["id"]=>58,
       ["name"]=>"Bert",
       ["company_id"]=>1,
       ["profession"]=>"IT Specialist";
   )
   [3]=>array(
       ["id"]=>60,
       ["name"]=>"Roy",
       ["company_id"]=>3,
       ["profession"]=>"Plumber";
   )
)
```

now my problem is I need to search all company_id = 1 and put it in array form with all his keys and values inside.

Comment: So write code that does it

Comment: What is your concrete programming question? What have you tried so far? What did not work? Also what's so wrong with the many duplicates we have on the website that show how it works?

Comment: thanks guys.. mr. Mark M. have show me the answer.. and it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$new_arr = array();

foreach ($arr as $a)
    if ($a['company_id']==1)
        $new_arr[] = $a;

print_r($new_arr);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 56
            [name] => john
            [company_id] => 1
            [profession] => IT
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 58
            [name] => Bert
            [company_id] => 1
            [profession] => IT Specialist
        )

)
```

OR, if you don't want `company_id` included in the new array, where `company_id` is always 1, then

```
$new_arr = array();
foreach ($arr as $a)
    if ($a['company_id']==1) {
        unset($a['company_id']);
        $new_arr[] = $a;
    }

print_r($new_array);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 56
            [name] => john
            [profession] => IT
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 58
            [name] => Bert
            [profession] => IT Specialist
        )

)
```

Comment: thanks you sir.. I didn't know much in Php.. I'm new here.. that works.. the only syntax that I lack of is the foreach, thanks you a lot.. thats save my day...

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it using `array_filter()`:

```
$a = array_filter($a, function($v){return $v['company_id']==1;});
```